# python: split string after a character

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string with two "-"

```
467.2-123-hdxdlfow
```

I want to remove everything after the second "-" so that I get "467.2-123". What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [6]: "-".join('467.2-123-hdxdlfow'.split('-')[0:2])
Out[6]: '467.2-123'
```

Answer (score 13):

```
before, sep, after = theString.rpartition("-")
```

This splits the str about the last occurrence of "-" and your answer would be the variable `before`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 >>> s = '467.2-123-hdxdlfow'
 >>> s[:s.rfind('-')]
 '467.2-123'
```

Comment: I like this one best because it works for any number of dashes - it will get rid of the last one and anything after it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are after everything but the last element, I have modifed spicavigo's answer to exclude the last element.

```
a='467.2-123-hdxdlfow'
'-'.join(a.split('-')[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a='467.2-123-hdxdlfow'
'-'.join(a.split('-')[:2])
```

If you have exactly 2 '-', you could do

```
a.rsplit('-',1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
([^-]*-[^-]*)-.*
```

and ask the result for the first capturing group (`(...)` in the example).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `result = re.sub("([^-]*-[^-]*)(-.*$)", r"\1", '467.2-123-hdxdlfow')`
gives `467.2-123`